# Does size of table column impact database joins?

Tags: sql-server, database

A quick question on database joins. I am currently using MS SQL Server

If I have a column called tradeNo in table A of size  VARCHAR(10)  and if I have a similar column called tradeNo in table B of size  VARCHAR(50) .

Does the size impact when doing joins.

I am currently trying to do a left outer join between table A and table B and find it extremely slow.

Comment: An outer join will, by definition, include all the rows from one or both tables. So you might be getting to get a full table scan on one or both tables. Edit your question, and include `create table` and `insert` statements. Also include the execution plan.

Comment: You are joining tables on different datatypes here so an implicit conversion it taking place. This means you are likely only going to ever get an index scan instead of a seek. It isn't so much the size of the table (number of rows) as it is different datatypes that is causing your performance issues here.